# dig works but ping does not resolve host

Tags: domain-name-system

I've configured the DNS settings for a host (`admin.example-preprod.foobar.it` with IP `100.100.100.100`) but it does not resolve from every server I try (it does for some).

For example, I'm on a server which uses the following 3 DNS servers:

```
foobar@server:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 200.200.200.1
nameserver 200.200.200.2
nameserver 200.200.200.3
```

`dig` works for all of them.

first:

```
foobar@server:~$ dig admin.example-preprod.foobar.it @200.200.200.1

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.7-Ubuntu <<>> admin.example-preprod.foobar.it @200.200.200.1
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 6540
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 3, ADDITIONAL: 2
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;admin.example-preprod.foobar.it.        IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
admin.example-preprod.foobar.it. 86400 IN A      100.100.100.100

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
foobar.it.               86400   IN      NS      qwert.foobar.it.
foobar.it.               86400   IN      NS      ns0.xname.org.
foobar.it.               86400   IN      NS      ns1.xname.org.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
qwert.foobar.it.         86400   IN      A       200.200.200.1

;; Query time: 46 msec
;; SERVER: 200.200.200.1#53(200.200.200.1)
;; WHEN: Fri Nov 04 10:35:46 EET 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 156
```

second:

```
foobar@server:~$ dig admin.example-preprod.foobar.it @200.200.200.2

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.7-Ubuntu <<>> admin.example-preprod.foobar.it @200.200.200.2
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 40127
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;admin.example-preprod.foobar.it.        IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
foobar.it.               85817   IN      SOA     qwert.foobar.it. webmaster.foobar.it. 2016092901 10800 900 1814400 10800

;; Query time: 3 msec
;; SERVER: 200.200.200.2#53(200.200.200.2)
;; WHEN: Fri Nov 04 10:36:05 EET 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 111
```

third:

```
foobar@server:~$ dig admin.example-preprod.foobar.it @200.200.200.3

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.7-Ubuntu <<>> admin.example-preprod.foobar.it @200.200.200.3
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 2392
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 3, ADDITIONAL: 2

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;admin.example-preprod.foobar.it.        IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
admin.example-preprod.foobar.it. 86400 IN A      100.100.100.100

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
foobar.it.               86400   IN      NS      qwert.foobar.it.
foobar.it.               86400   IN      NS      ns1.xname.org.
foobar.it.               86400   IN      NS      ns0.xname.org.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
qwert.foobar.it.         81845   IN      A       200.200.200.1

;; Query time: 2309 msec
;; SERVER: 200.200.200.3#53(200.200.200.3)
;; WHEN: Fri Nov 04 10:35:56 EET 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 156
```

but then, when I try to ping it gives me `unknown host`:

```
foobar@server:~$ ping admin.example-preprod.foobar.it
ping: unknown host admin.example-preprod.foobar.it
```

How is that possible and where should I look at to solve the problem?

Comment: Can you add the output of `cat /etc/nsswitch.conf` to your question.

Comment: What's the version of Linux on the clients? Are you using `nscd` on the clients? What do you get as output from `getent hosts admin.example-preprod.foobar.it`

Comment: @Thomas it's the default in ubuntu 14.04.4: http://pastebin.com/raw/y6Eiva0W

Comment: @PaulHaldane vanilla Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS. No, `nscd` is not installed.The output of that command is empty but doing `getent hosts www.google.com` gives me `2607:f8b0:4002:806::2004 www.google.com`.

Comment: Thanks for the help comments - I came here for a similar issue and eventually realized I had an errant entry in `/etc/hosts`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dig doesn't work for all of them - your second nameserver (`200.200.200.2` in your example) isn't resolving the record.

The Linux resolver randomises between entries in resolv.conf by default and I'd guess your ping has hit the failing resolver.

Comment: It's not resolving it but it is providing a way to resolve it (giving the SOA), isn't that right?

Comment: Nope - look at the status of the answer from that server - `NXDOMAIN`. That means it is authoritative for the zone and knows that the record doesn't exist.

Comment: Given that these nameservers are general system resolvers I'd consider that one out of three disagreeing with the majority points to a problem with that resolver.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why yet, but commenting out ALL things in `/private/etc/hosts` seemed to fix a situation where dig worked but ping didn't (dig does not look at hosts but ping does)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had forgotten that I had made an entry in /private/etc/hosts and needed to remove it. I had been trying to access a domain on my LAN server, but then I set up the same domain on a cloud VM.

Answer (score 0):

On my Debian 11 I had similar issue for xxx.local domain name because of mDNS enabled. mDNS handles all reguests to .local zone and fails in my case.

To disable mDNS I changed my /etc/nsswitch.conf like this:

```
#hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname
hosts:          files dns myhostname
```